DST aware shift in polars
I'm working with a dataset that is dependent on local dates and times. I want to add a lag so a row has access to the values from the previous n days. The challenge here comes from the DST transitions. Sometimes there are too few or too many records in one of the previous days. For example, when changing to summer time and using a half hour periodicity I could get:
┌───────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ timestamp                     ┆ value     │ lag_value │
│ ---                           ┆ ---       │ ---       │
│ datetime[ms, Europe/Brussels] ┆ f64       │ f64       │
╞═══════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2017-03-26 00:00:00 CET       ┆ -0.453049 │ ...       │
│ 2017-03-26 00:30:00 CET       ┆ 1.696162  │ ...       │
│ 2017-03-26 01:00:00 CET       ┆ 0.10527   │ ...       │
│ 2017-03-26 01:30:00 CET       ┆ 0.93969   │ ...       │
│ 2017-03-26 03:00:00 CEST      ┆ 1.158872  │ ...       │ <-
│ 2017-03-26 03:30:00 CEST      ┆ -0.158087 │ ...       │
...

where values for the local time of 02:00 and 02:30 are missing. I am using half an hour here to make sure it isn't too verbose but I'm looking for a solution that works for any periodicity (that is a divisor of 60), e.g. 10 minutes. The DST strategy is easy: if there are too many records then pick the first entry. For example, if 01:00 appears twice the first value should be used. In the above case, with missing data, the missing value should be filled backwards so the values at 03:00 and 03:30 should be used as replacements for the missing values at 02:00 and 02:30. The expected result is thus:
┌───────────────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ timestamp                     ┆ value     │ lag_value │
│ ---                           ┆ ---       │ ---       │
│ datetime[ms, Europe/Brussels] ┆ f64       │ f64       │
╞═══════════════════════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2017-03-27 00:00:00 CEST      ┆ 2.358506  │ -0.453049 │
│ 2017-03-27 00:30:00 CEST      ┆ -1.235676 │ 1.696162  │
│ 2017-03-27 01:00:00 CEST      ┆ -0.430255 │ 0.10527   │
│ 2017-03-27 01:30:00 CEST      ┆ -1.460279 │ 0.93969   │
│ 2017-03-27 02:00:00 CEST      ┆ -0.918418 │ 1.158872  │ x
│ 2017-03-27 02:30:00 CEST      ┆ -0.933531 │ -0.158087 │ x
│ 2017-03-27 03:00:00 CEST      ┆ -0.421031 │ 1.158872  │
│ 2017-03-27 03:30:00 CEST      ┆ -0.800223 │ -0.158087 │
...

I have tried with a generic shift, as you can fix the DST issue by then doing a partial shift of the affected/wrong columns of 2 entries backward/forward. However, I cannot find how to do a partial shift in some columns from a given index.
Alternatively, I can calculate a second dataframe and join it with the first dataframe. This would ideally create None values, but runs into other polars issues:
from datetime import datetime
df = pl.DataFrame({"localdatetime": [datetime(2017, 3, 27, 2)]}).with_columns(pl.col("localdatetime").dt.replace_time_zone("Europe/Brussels"))

df = df.with_columns(
    polars
    .col("localdatetime")
    .dt.offset_by("-1d")
    .alias("localdatetime_YTD")
)

>>> polars.exceptions.ComputeError: datetime '2017-03-26 02:00:00' is non-existent in time zone 'Europe/Brussels'. You may be able to use `non_existent='null'` to return `null` in this case.

A backward fill or forward fill works for hourly data as only a single value is missing, but does not work for finer granularity of 30 minutes or less. The gap in these cases is more than a single row and the outlined DST strategy is to shift a block of an entire hour, not simply fill with the next/last known value.

I see 2 problems there
First, upsampling. To create missing rows in your DataFrame, you can use DataFrame.upsample().
Second, filling gaps with shifted data. Unfortunately, DataFrame.shift() expects scalar as parameter, so you can't use it dynamically. If you know that you only have one continuous gap, you can do it very simple by fetching the size of gap first:
# example DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": [1,2,3,None,None,4,5,6,],
    }
)

┌───────┐
│ value │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
│ 2     │
│ 3     │
│ null  │
│ null  │
│ 4     │
│ 5     │
│ 6     │
└───────┘

x = len(df.filter(pl.col("value").is_null()))

df.fill_null(pl.col("value").shift(-x))

┌───────┐
│ value │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
│ 2     │
│ 3     │
│ 4     │ # filled
│ 5     │ # values
│ 4     │
│ 5     │
│ 6     │
└───────┘


There are no missing rows, so I don't think upsampling has anything to add. Your idea for shift may work though if an offset with a join (and filling in null values that way) could be make to work. However, offsetting local datetime can lead to weirdness. I added an example to the original question.
